# How to make switching between windows in XQuartz work again

Tags: keyboard, big-sur, x11, xquartz

After an upgrade to Big Sur I am no longer able to use `⌘ Cmd` + `` ` `` to switch between windows in XQuartz.

Previously, like on this MacOS Mojave with the same version of XQuartz (2.8.0_beta1)
installed, the window menu looked like this:
[image]

Now, after upgrade to Big Sur, it looks like this:
[image]

Is there anything I can do to get my `⌘ Cmd` + `` ` `` back in Big Sur?
Is it possible that some keyboard mapping in the Big Sur is preventing "Cycle Through Windows"
from appearing in just XQuartz? In other application (Finder, Chrome, etc.) it works as expected.

Thanks